# Reemplazar todos las letras por campos vacios en JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Quiero realizar un método que reemplace todas las letras de los registros por campos vacios, ya que los registros aparecen de la siguiente manera:
21002000007  ISR Retenido  (21002000007) y quiero que aparezcan así: 21002000007
Tambien quisiera que se quitara el dato repetido (21002000007) pero aun no se me ocurre como hacerlo.
Este es el metodo donde busco quitar las letras, funciona bien el replace all pero solo funciona para un solo carácter, si pongo todas las letras del abecedario no quita los caracteres.

```
public void quitarLetras() {
            DefaultTableModel dfTD = (DefaultTableModel) tablaPorFechas.getModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < dfTD.getRowCount(); i++) {
    
                String columnaRegistros = (String) tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(i, 0);
                String replaceAll = columnaRegistros.replaceAll("r", "");
                tablaPorFechas.setValueAt(replaceAll, i, 0);
            }
        }
```

¿Algun consejo de que utilizar para que si tome todas las letras y las cambie por campos vacios?.
De antemano muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione solo ocupe especificar que solo quería que se mostraran los primeros caracteres en los resultados de mi columna en consulta sql con un:  `SUBSTRING (columna, 1,10)`